# Query to AWS database always times out

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services

I have an app that consists of a Postgres database deployed to AWS, a React frontend and a Node backend, both separately deployed to Heroku. My problem is that when I go to query the database, the request always times out. This never happened when I was running my app locally but still had the database deployed. I have my AWS VPC group set to allow all inbound and outbound traffic. Can anyone help me figure out what's wrong? Below are the AWS error logs:

```
Viewing Log: error/postgresql.log.2020-05-04-02 (3.2 kB)
2020-05-04 02:00:21 UTC::@:[5256]:LOG: checkpoint starting: time
2020-05-04 02:00:21 UTC::@:[5256]:LOG: checkpoint complete: wrote 1 buffers (0.0%); 0 WAL file(s) added, 0 removed, 1 recycled; write=0.101 s, sync=0.002 s, total=0.109 s; sync files=1, longest=0.002 s, average=0.002 s; distance=16384 kB, estimate=16385 kB
2020-05-04 02:05:21 UTC::@:[5256]:LOG: checkpoint starting: time
2020-05-04 02:05:21 UTC::@:[5256]:LOG: checkpoint complete: wrote 1 buffers (0.0%); 0 WAL file(s) added, 0 removed, 1 recycled; write=0.101 s, sync=0.001 s, total=0.109 s; sync files=1, longest=0.001 s, average=0.001 s; distance=16384 kB, estimate=16385 kB
2020-05-04 02:10:21 UTC::@:[5256]:LOG: checkpoint starting: time
2020-05-04 02:10:21 UTC::@:[5256]:LOG: checkpoint complete: wrote 1 buffers (0.0%); 0 WAL file(s) added, 0 removed, 1 recycled; write=0.101 s, sync=0.002 s, total=0.109 s; sync files=1, longest=0.002 s, average=0.002 s; distance=16384 kB, estimate=16384 kB
2020-05-04 02:15:21 UTC::@:[5256]:LOG: checkpoint starting: time
2020-05-04 02:15:21 UTC::@:[5256]:LOG: checkpoint complete: wrote 1 buffers (0.0%); 0 WAL file(s) added, 0 removed, 1 recycled; write=0.101 s, sync=0.002 s, total=0.110 s; sync files=1, longest=0.002 s, average=0.002 s; distance=16384 kB, estimate=16384 kB
2020-05-04 02:20:21 UTC::@:[5256]:LOG: checkpoint starting: time
2020-05-04 02:20:21 UTC::@:[5256]:LOG: checkpoint complete: wrote 1 buffers (0.0%); 0 WAL file(s) added, 0 removed, 1 recycled; write=0.101 s, sync=0.001 s, total=0.110 s; sync files=1, longest=0.001 s, average=0.001 s; distance=16384 kB, estimate=16384 kB
2020-05-04 02:25:21 UTC::@:[5256]:LOG: checkpoint starting: time
2020-05-04 02:25:21 UTC::@:[5256]:LOG: checkpoint complete: wrote 1 buffers (0.0%); 0 WAL file(s) added, 0 removed, 1 recycled; write=0.101 s, sync=0.001 s, total=0.109 s; sync files=1, longest=0.001 s, average=0.001 s; distance=16384 kB, estimate=16384 kB
2020-05-04 02:30:21 UTC::@:[5256]:LOG: checkpoint starting: time
2020-05-04 02:30:21 UTC::@:[5256]:LOG: checkpoint complete: wrote 1 buffers (0.0%); 0 WAL file(s) added, 0 removed, 1 recycled; write=0.101 s, sync=0.001 s, total=0.109 s; sync files=1, longest=0.001 s, average=0.001 s; distance=16384 kB, estimate=16384 kB
2020-05-04 02:35:21 UTC::@:[5256]:LOG: checkpoint starting: time
2020-05-04 02:35:21 UTC::@:[5256]:LOG: checkpoint complete: wrote 1 buffers (0.0%); 0 WAL file(s) added, 0 removed, 1 recycled; write=0.101 s, sync=0.001 s, total=0.109 s; sync files=1, longest=0.001 s, average=0.001 s; distance=16384 kB, estimate=16384 kB
2020-05-04 02:40:22 UTC::@:[5256]:LOG: checkpoint starting: time
2020-05-04 02:40:22 UTC::@:[5256]:LOG: checkpoint complete: wrote 1 buffers (0.0%); 0 WAL file(s) added, 0 removed, 1 recycled; write=0.101 s, sync=0.002 s, total=0.109 s; sync files=1, longest=0.002 s, average=0.002 s; distance=16384 kB, estimate=16384 kB
2020-05-04 02:45:22 UTC::@:[5256]:LOG: checkpoint starting: time
2020-05-04 02:45:22 UTC::@:[5256]:LOG: checkpoint complete: wrote 1 buffers (0.0%); 0 WAL file(s) added, 0 removed, 1 recycled; write=0.101 s, sync=0.001 s, total=0.109 s; sync files=1, longest=0.001 s, average=0.001 s; distance=16384 kB, estimate=16384 kB
----------------------- END OF LOG ----------------------
```

The Security Group configuration is:

[image: Security group]

[image: Security group]

Comment: Is your RDS setup to Allow Public Access? By default it is off.

Comment: A time-out normally indicates that there is no network connection. Can you show us the configuration of the Security Group associated with the database? Is the database in a public subnet?

Comment: @Marcin Yes, it's set to public.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein I can't edit my post to add pictures but I believe this is what you're asking for? https://imgur.com/q41c1iV
https://imgur.com/SU6yeKa.
I don't know if it's in a public subnet, how should I check?

Comment: IP address in the inbound rule is for Hiroku or your local machine? To check vpc, go to vpc-id and check its cidr IP range. This at list will tell us if its default vpc with all subnets public or not a default one.

Comment: @Marcin My local machine I think? Ok here it is: https://imgur.com/RmAZOt7

Comment: Well if the ip in the inbound rules is for you local machine, then no other IP is going to be allowed, including Heroku systems.  Set it to `0.0.0.0/0` to check if this will allow heroku to connect to it. If it works, check IP of the Heroku system, and use its IP in your security group, to limit access only to Heroku (can also add your local IP as well). VPC is ok. Its default one.

Comment: The Security Group is configured to only allow inbound connections from the IP address `75.155.134.45`. If you did not change the configuration since using it from home, then this is the cause of the problem. It should be changed to the IP address where connections will originate. You should probably also limit it only to the necessary port (`5432`) rather than _All Traffic_.

Comment: That did the trick, thank you both for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Moving from comment to an answer...

The **Security Group** is configured to only permit inbound access from a single IP address.

Since your connection worked previously but is not working since you moved the application, it would suggest that this IP address is related to your local computer. You will need to change the IP address in the security group to were the traffic is now coming from.

You should probably also limit it only to the necessary port (`5432`) rather than *All Traffic*.